# Validation data considerably worse performance than stratified kfold cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, boosting

I've been working on a binary classifer for a NBA spread dataset and am running into an issue where the validation data has considerablly lower performance than the test/train cross validation.

I am using the XGBoost Classifer on a total of 15266 games starting in the 06 season and running until last month. I know that the data sample size is pretty small but for this domain it is literally all of the data that I think is available which contains the spread/moneylines or at least all of the data I was able to find/scrape

The cross validation results are better than I would have expected considering the difficulty of the task but the validation data(last 2500x data points) is considerably worse than the cross validation results.

Below are the classification reports for each fold(Stratified Kfold):

```
Fold #1
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.57      0.80      0.67      1320
           1       0.63      0.36      0.46      1234

   micro avg       0.59      0.59      0.59      2554
   macro avg       0.60      0.58      0.57      2554
weighted avg       0.60      0.59      0.57      2554

Fold #2

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.58      0.81      0.67      1320
           1       0.64      0.38      0.47      1233

   micro avg       0.60      0.60      0.60      2553
   macro avg       0.61      0.59      0.57      2553
weighted avg       0.61      0.60      0.58      2553

Fold #3
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.57      0.80      0.67      1320
           1       0.63      0.36      0.46      1233

   micro avg       0.59      0.59      0.59      2553
   macro avg       0.60      0.58      0.57      2553
weighted avg       0.60      0.59      0.57      2553

Fold #4

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.58      0.81      0.68      1320
           1       0.64      0.37      0.47      1233

   micro avg       0.60      0.60      0.60      2553
   macro avg       0.61      0.59      0.57      2553
weighted avg       0.61      0.60      0.58      2553

Fold #5


              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.59      0.84      0.69      1320
           1       0.68      0.37      0.48      1233

   micro avg       0.61      0.61      0.61      2553
   macro avg       0.64      0.61      0.59      2553
weighted avg       0.63      0.61      0.59      2553
```

Below is the xgboost scores for each fold and the mean scores for the test and validaton data

```
kfold train scores mean 0.6256264979362992
kfold train scores [0.6171171171171171, 0.6441789875648684, 0.6263585626162734, 0.6257710760795065, 0.6147067463037306]
kfold test score mean 0.5979952340069461
kfold test scores [0.5908379013312451, 0.5977281629455542, 0.5898942420681551, 0.5981198589894242, 0.6133960047003525]
val scores mean 0.5119199999999999
val scores [0.5168, 0.504, 0.5156, 0.506, 0.5172]
```

Here are the scores/classification reports for the model trained on the full dataset and the validation data

```
train score 0.6145811573010236
test score 0.5902255639097744
validation score 0.5196
test report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.57      0.82      0.67      1633
           1       0.65      0.35      0.45      1559

   micro avg       0.59      0.59      0.59      3192
   macro avg       0.61      0.58      0.56      3192
weighted avg       0.61      0.59      0.57      3192

val report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.52      0.99      0.68      1292
           1       0.65      0.01      0.02      1208

   micro avg       0.52      0.52      0.52      2500
   macro avg       0.59      0.50      0.35      2500
weighted avg       0.58      0.52      0.36      2500
```

In the validation data classification report the recall/f1-score for the positive class is a pretty big red flag to me.

What could be the possible issue/issues here with the model? Over fitting, Under fitting, etc? What would be some possible solutions?

Comment: after working on this for several days I finally solved it. I was able to get both the cross validation results and validation data results to be roughly the same and at 64%. There were numerious issues with my data which after solving those issues the results stabilized and are far better than I could have hoped given the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: i'm going to stop asking questions here and just start asking them in the kaggle forums. So far I'm 0/2 on getting any responses whatsoever. I deleted my other question and moved it to that forum where I may actually get some sort of response